# Android AsyncTask doInBackground Runtime Exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-process

I have this simple function that registers the user on the Google Messaging service

```
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regId = gcm.register(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                        + regId);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

                storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
                appUtil.shareRegIdWithAppServer(context, regId);
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "should be rig: " + msg);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
            }
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Registered with GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

**Edite**

```
private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}
```

**End edite** 
When I execute it, it successfully registers on the GCM server and the user gets his registration ID successfully. **BUT** I get the following exception that stops and closes the application.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.sparr_000.newgcm, PID: 25967
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

I am new to android. I have read the documentation, watched related videos and searched online but I found no solution.
What is wrong with my code and **How can I get rid off this exception and continue running my app in peace?**

Comment: is this the complete stack trace ?

Comment: No @Dexter there is a lot of bunch of error lines... I don't think that posting them is good idea

Comment: Filtering by errors from your app certainly is a good idea

Comment: I suspect this line `storeRegistrationId(context, regId);` is the culprit. You are using `context` from another thread which may cause problems if you update the ui, for example. Try to return the  `regId` and store it in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @codeMagic do you want me to edit the question with all the red lines error message? just ask I will do anything to solve this shit

Comment: Yes but make sure you are filtering your app's logs and not the entire device

Comment: Id say hes just using that context for shared pref stuff. Do provide the relevant stacktrace

Comment: What should I filter exactly I am confused

Comment: @AndyRes that might be right but what do you suggest to change?

Comment: Instead of constructing `msg` in `doInBackground()` and displaying it in `onPostExecute()`, return just the `regId` alone from the doInBackground, and construct the message in `onPostExecute()`. `onPostExecute()` runs on UI thread, so there you should call `storeRegistrationId(context, regId)`

Comment: @AndyRes I did exactly as you said but I get same result look:
http://jsfiddle.net/w6uatsL7/

Comment: I see you moved `shareRegIdWithServer()` also in `onPostExecute()`, this is good, but make sure the code in that method is executed on a separate thread, otherwise you may get NetworkOnMaiThreadException, as in Android you are not allowed to make http requests from the main thread.... But all this are assumptions, you better look in logcat for the stacktrace. As others pointed, the error log you posted is incomplete, as it should show exactly the line number in the code that generated the crash.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many places where the error might be as you have code running after the registration. Try to break your code into small pieces or use a debugger to know which step fails. Like comment out   storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
                    appUtil.shareRegIdWithAppServer(context, regId);
and try running if it works then add the next or debug the rest of the functions to know which one fails. 
Instead of sending the context, get the context of you application from the current class.

Comment: Your doInBackground() fails because the thread life cycle was not completed successfully. Just debug and check for the other 2 methods.